# how to get data from laravel5.5?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.5 and I want to view my data in database from my view page (home.blade.php)

```html
 <table>
                        <tbody>
                    @foreach($home as $key => $data)
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{$data->created_at}}</th>
                            <th>{{$data->category}}</th>
                            <th>{{$data->reportitle}}</th>
                            <th>{{$data->reportdetails}}</th>
                            <th>{{$data->seenstat}}</th>
                            <th>{{$data->actionstat}}</th>
                            <th>{{$data->donestat}}</th>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

In my home.blade.php I have an empty table and I want to show data from database fyp:

```js
 Route::get('home', function () {

        $fyp = DB::table('reports')->get();

        return view('home', ['fyp' => $fyp]);

    });
```

Comment: You passed `$fyp` variable not `$home`.  Loop through `$fyp` variable

Answer (score 2):

This must work (as @Nazmul said):

```
@foreach($fyp as $data)
    <tr>
        <th>{{$data->created_at}}</th>
        <th>{{$data->category}}</th>
        <th>{{$data->reportitle}}</th>
        <th>{{$data->reportdetails}}</th>
        <th>{{$data->seenstat}}</th>
        <th>{{$data->actionstat}}</th>
        <th>{{$data->donestat}}</th>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

just follow the code

```
Route::get('home', function () {

            $home = DB::table('reports')->get();

            return view('home', compact('home'));

});
```

After in your view page

```
<table>
                        <tbody>
                    @foreach($home as $key => $data)
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{$data->created_at}}</th>
                            <th>{{$data->category}}</th>
                            <th>{{$data->reportitle}}</th>
                            <th>{{$data->reportdetails}}</th>
                            <th>{{$data->seenstat}}</th>
                            <th>{{$data->actionstat}}</th>
                            <th>{{$data->donestat}}</th>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

I hope this will help you.